# Cannot access AWS domain purchased with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I recently purchased a domain on AWS `mydomain.com` with the intention of creating a record set which can forward traffic to an EC2 instance which I also have running.  However, when I try to access `mydomain.com` from a web browser, I get the error that the site cannot be reached.

The record set I created for this domain was `myapp.mydomain.com`.  I configured this to point to my EC2 instance.  When I try to access this domain from a web browser, I get a 502 bad gateway error.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: can you access the app inside the instance or with the IP directly? can you show your DNS configuration?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran Not 100% sure, but I have a rule to (temporarily) allow all incoming TCP trrafic to the app.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start by creating a zone in Route53 for the domain - so mydomain.com, NOT anything else.

Once that has been created, there will be 2 records: SOA and NS.

Using the "Registered Domains" screen, click on the domain and make sure that the name server records match the NS records in the zone you created.

Once that is done, you should be able to create a new A record in the mydomain.com zone for myapp.mydomain.com that points to the IP address of your EC2 instance.

Comment: Hi Chris, the steps you gave are basically what the AWS documentation says, and which I have already followed.  Is there some test I can do to see if my EC2 is reachable from the outside?  Do I need Tomcat or another web server running?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: your question was around Route53 & DNS - seems like you're expanding it.  So you should probably update the question with additional information, or ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Chris, the thing is that even after configuring route 53, I still got 502 from the URL.  It was not until something was listening on a certain port that I got an expected response.

Comment: I have never had a 502 from an EC2 instance, but it is very common to get that from a load balancer.  Could you have had a stale DNS entry pointing to an empty ELB?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @chris, which closely follows the official documentation from AWS, is in general the best answer to this question.  However, in my case, the 502 error I saw was being caused by that I did not open port 8080 on which my Tomcat server was listening.  By adding a custom TCP rule to open port 8080 I was then able to reach my Tomcat.